# Trying to get my raspberry pi to work as a server with cloudflare again

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, server, dns

I am trying to get my raspberry pi working as a server again. I unplugged it a while ago, and I am guessing I am forgetting to do something I need to do to get it running again. In the cloudflare dashboard, everything looks correct - it is seeing the correct IP for my domain. The necessary port is open in my router settings for my raspberry pi IP on my network. I am using ddclient as shown here: https://www.cloudflare.com/technical- resources/#ddclient.

The behaviour of the problem is that when I go to my `www.domain.xyz:8080/heater/1` (which should give back a JSON response) it gives the google browser error:

```
This site can’t be reached
xxx.xyz refused to connect.
Search Google for xxx xyz 8080 heater
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My ddclient.conf configuration looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com/, web-skip='IP Address'
ssl=yes

protocol=cloudflare
server=www.cloudflare.com
login=eamon.white7@gmail.com
password=xxx
zone=ewizard.xyz
ewizard.xyz
```

This is my debug output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet
=== opt ====
opt{cache}                           : <undefined>
opt{cmd}                             : <undefined>
opt{cmd-skip}                        : <undefined>
opt{daemon}                          : 0
opt{debug}                           : 1
opt{exec}                            : <undefined>
opt{facility}                        : <undefined>
opt{file}                            : <undefined>
opt{force}                           : <undefined>
opt{foreground}                      : <undefined>
opt{fw}                              : <undefined>
opt{fw-login}                        : <undefined>
opt{fw-password}                     : <undefined>
opt{fw-skip}                         : <undefined>
opt{geturl}                          : <undefined>
opt{help}                            : <undefined>
opt{host}                            : <undefined>
opt{if}                              : <undefined>
opt{if-skip}                         : <undefined>
opt{ip}                              : <undefined>
opt{login}                           : <undefined>
opt{mail}                            : <undefined>
opt{mail-failure}                    : <undefined>
opt{max-interval}                    : 2160000
opt{min-error-interval}              : 300
opt{min-interval}                    : 30
opt{options}                         : <undefined>
opt{password}                        : <undefined>
opt{pid}                             : <undefined>
opt{postscript}                      : <undefined>
opt{priority}                        : <undefined>
opt{protocol}                        : <undefined>
opt{proxy}                           : <undefined>
opt{query}                           : <undefined>
opt{quiet}                           : 0
opt{retry}                           : <undefined>
opt{server}                          : <undefined>
opt{ssl}                             : <undefined>
opt{syslog}                          : <undefined>
opt{test}                            : <undefined>
opt{timeout}                         : <undefined>
opt{use}                             : <undefined>
opt{verbose}                         : 1
opt{web}                             : <undefined>
opt{web-skip}                        : <undefined>
=== globals ====
globals{daemon}                      : 60
globals{debug}                       : 1
globals{login}                       : eamon.white7@gmail.com
globals{password}                    : xxx
globals{protocol}                    : cloudflare
globals{quiet}                       : 0
globals{server}                      : www.cloudflare.com
globals{ssl}                         : 1
globals{use}                         : web
globals{verbose}                     : 1
globals{web}                         : checkip.dyndns.com/
globals{web-skip}                    : IP Address
globals{zone}                        : xxx.xyz
=== config ====
config{ewizard.xyz}{atime}           : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{backupmx}        : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{cacheable}       : ARRAY(0x226fdf8)
config{ewizard.xyz}{cmd}             : <undefined>
config{ewizard.xyz}{cmd-skip}        : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{fw}              : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{fw-login}        : <undefined>
config{ewizard.xyz}{fw-password}     : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{fw-skip}         : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{host}            : xxx.xyz
config{ewizard.xyz}{if}              : ppp0
config{ewizard.xyz}{if-skip}         : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{ip}              : <undefined>
config{ewizard.xyz}{login}           : eamon.white7@gmail.com
config{ewizard.xyz}{max-interval}    : 2160000
config{ewizard.xyz}{min-error-interval} : 300
config{ewizard.xyz}{min-interval}    : 300
config{ewizard.xyz}{mtime}           : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{mx}              : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{password}        : a98eb4a7cc29f1edd1a555d639dc41aebe18c
config{ewizard.xyz}{protocol}        : cloudflare
config{ewizard.xyz}{server}          : www.cloudflare.com
config{ewizard.xyz}{static}          : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{status}          : 
config{ewizard.xyz}{use}             : web
config{ewizard.xyz}{warned-min-error-interval} : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{warned-min-interval} : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{web}             : checkip.dyndns.com/
config{ewizard.xyz}{web-skip}        : IP Address
config{ewizard.xyz}{wildcard}        : 0
config{ewizard.xyz}{wtime}           : 30
config{ewizard.xyz}{zone}            : xxx.xyz
=== cache ====
cache{ewizard.xyz}{atime}            : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{backupmx}         : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{host}             : xxx.xyz
cache{ewizard.xyz}{ip}               : 209.6.13.228
cache{ewizard.xyz}{mtime}            : 1513478181
cache{ewizard.xyz}{mx}               : 
cache{ewizard.xyz}{static}           : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{status}           : 
cache{ewizard.xyz}{warned-min-error-interval} : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{warned-min-interval} : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{wildcard}         : 0
cache{ewizard.xyz}{wtime}            : 30
DEBUG:    proxy  = 
DEBUG:    url    = checkip.dyndns.com/
DEBUG:    server = checkip.dyndns.com
CONNECT:  checkip.dyndns.com
CONNECTED:  using HTTP
SENDING:  GET / HTTP/1.0
SENDING:   Host: checkip.dyndns.com
SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.3
SENDING:   Connection: close
SENDING:   
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
RECEIVE:  Content-Type: text/html
RECEIVE:  Server: DynDNS-CheckIP/1.0.1
RECEIVE:  Connection: close
RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Pragma: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Content-Length: 104
RECEIVE:  
RECEIVE:  <html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 209.6.13.228</body></html>
DEBUG:    get_ip: using web, checkip.dyndns.com/ reports 209.6.13.228
SUCCESS:  xxx.xyz: skipped: IP address was already set to 209.6.13.228.
```

Comment: Have you checked your network connection?

Comment: yes...it wasnt anything having to do with cloudflare...i needed to serve what i was doing a different way...i used laravel and i was just serving it with the development command. I found a stack question for how to run laravel on apache and got everything working that way instead of using a port other than apache.